# Probability per year calculations

Tags: probability, statistics

Trying to work out the probability of a fault occuring over a 12.5 year time period. The probability of a fault occuring per year is 1/15.

Does this mean the probability of no fault occuring over the period is (14/15)^12.5 = 0.422

And of one fault occuring 1 - 0.422 = 0.578?

How could I go about calculating the probabilty of two faults occuring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to use the poisson distribution formula, where you multiply your probably of the event happening over a time period by the time period within you wish to know the answers and sub this in with how many times the success happens.

Answer (score 0):

If we can assure that successive faults occurring are independent of each other.Then you can simply multiply those probabilities.

**Probability of Two Independent Events**

P(A and B)=P(A) x P(B)

Comment: I realise I made a mistake in what I was asking, the probability if given as 1/15 per year, so how can I deal with the half year at the end?

Comment: Does this mean that if I multiply the probability of one fault happening over the time period by itself I'll get the right answer?

Comment: I think it would work.

Comment: Thanks, am I right in thinking that it should still add to one if combined with the relevant probabilities? just wondered as a way to check my answers, or does it not always have to add to 1?